# apacheの権限について

Tags: php, apache

phpでテキストファイルを作成するとき、apacheはユーザーが"_www"でグループが"_www"なのに、所有者が"(自分)"でグループが"staff"のフォルダに対して作成することが出来るのはどういう仕組なんでしょうか？
そのフォルダのパーミッションは0755です。

Comment: これは CGI か mod_php かの差によるものだと思われます。
@sysy さんの環境で CGI か mod_php か確認したい場合は `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` で Server API という項目を確認してください。そこに `CGI/FastCGI` とあれば CGI モード、`Apache 云々` と書いてあれば CGI で動作しているものと思われます。

Answer (score 2):

おそらく、その環境では SuEXEC という仕組みが導入されており、PHPはCGIモードで動作しているのだと思います。

SuEXEC が有効になっている場合、CGI プログラムはユーザ権限で実行されるため、そのユーザの所有するディレクトリに書き込むことが出来ます。

参考: [suEXEC サポート](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ja/suexec.html)

Comment: phpinfo の Server API は「Apache 2.0 Handler」でした。
SuEXEC は初めて知ったので自分でもちょっと調べてみたんですけど、SuEXEC が有効かどうかは Apache のエラーログに
suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: suexecのパス) 
があるとの事なので見てみたんですが、無かったので有効ではないのかもしれません。